# UWP Navigation View disappeared

Tags: uwp

I have NavigationView with 3 Buttons

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            ItemInvoked="nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked"
            IsTabStop="False"
            AlwaysShowHeader="False"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Grid.RowSpan="1" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Padding="0,0,0,0" >
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Nav_BlankPage1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_BlankPage1" Text="Nav_BlankPage1" />
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Nav_BlankPage2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_BlankPage2"   Text="Nav_BlankPage2"/>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Nav_BlankPage3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_BlankPage3"   Text="Nav_BlankPage3" />
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" 
           Grid.Column="1" 
           Grid.Row="1"
           VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,0,0,0">
            <RelativePanel Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="1">
             </RelativePanel>
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>
```

Code behind MainPage:

```
private void nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        TextBlock ItemContent = args.InvokedItem as TextBlock;
        if (ItemContent != null)
        {
            switch (ItemContent.Tag)
            {
                case "Nav_BlankPage1":
                    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));

                    break;
                case "Nav_BlankPage2":
                    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));

                    break;
                case "Nav_BlankPage3":
                    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage3));

                    break;
                case "Nav_Settings":

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every Page has 3 buttons (code behind for the first):

```
private void btnBlankPage1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
    _frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
}
```

If I use `NavigationView` buttons everything is fine, but if I use buttons on the Page `NavigationView` disappeared.

Could you please clarify?

Comment: I found one way: in MainPage: public static Frame GlobalFrame; and in constructor GlobalFrame = MainFrame; and later use only GlobalFrame. But it does not looks like a good way. Anyway it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are navigating using the wrong `Frame`. The UI tree looks kind of like this in your case:

- Window

  - **Frame**

    - NavigationViewPage

      - **MainFrame**

        - Page

When you navigate through the `NavigationView` menu, things are okay, as you are using the inner `MainFrame`. However, on the other page you take the `Frame` at the root of the `Window` (`(Frame)Window.Current.Content`) and navigate in it. This navigates away the page containing the `NavigationView` and navigates in `BlankPage1` on its place and hence the `NavigationView` disappears.

Instead you must navigate using `MainFrame` in the `NavigationView`. The easiest way to do this would be to add a `Frame` property to the page that contains the `NavigationView` and then use it for navigation:

```
public static Frame AppFrame { get; private set; }
```

And in the page constructor you assign it:

```
AppFrame = MainFrame;
```

Now you use this to navigate:

```
NavigationViewPage.AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

Where `NavigationViewPage` is the page that contains the `NavigationView`

Finally a note - you don't have to apologize for posting a question, that's what this site is for ;-) .